# Using Duplicate Detection to enter a 1/0 in a separate column

Tags: excel, vba

The conditional formatting options works well to identify duplicates. How could I use the detected duplicates to write a value to a separate column? 1 for duplicate, 0 for not a duplicate. I thought I could use a VBA function based on the cell colour. Excel however does not store the dup detected cell color in the normal cell color property.

Note: 99 is not the light red color number, it's just for reference.

```
Function LightRed(rng As Range) As Boolean
    If rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 99 Then
        LightRed = 0
    Else
        LightRed = 1
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I agree with pnuts, best to use a countif formula to find duplicates. In cell B1 and copy down: `=--(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tigeravatar said, you can use

```
=--(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1)
```

to detect duplicates and then you can apply a condition formatting on Column B where if cell value = 1, change background color to red

[image: Duplicate]